# IE 8 throwing error on CNAME redirection for ssl

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https, internet-explorer-8

I have a domain say 'abc.example.com' for which I have ssl certificate. This particular domain actually is CNAME'd to 'xyz.exampleapi.com'. Apache running on xyz.exampleapi.com has the certificate for 'abc.example.com' and it works fine for all modern browsers, i.e. Chrome/Fx etc.

Opening 'abc.example.com' the content is rendered from xyz.exampleapi.com and it works perfectly.

But for IE 8 I get, root certificate not valid for xyz.exampleapi.com. What I fail to understand is why is IE 8 checking the certificate of CNAME'd domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for IE 8 I get, root certificate not valid for xyz.exampleapi.com. What I fail to understand is why is IE 8 checking the certificate of CNAME'd domain.

My guess is that the issue is not strictly related to CNAME at all, but that you need SNI (Server Name Indication) here because you've setup multiple certificates on the same IP address. IE8/XP does not support SNI. Check your site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for any issues related to SNI and also issues related to IE8.